# Force floating elements to shrink with CSS

Tags: css, css-float

How can I force .b to shrink to fit next to .a without using tables and without .b wrapping? .a should always display in full.

css:

```
div{
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.a{
    float:right
}

.b{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

html:

```
<div><span class='a'>a - text</span><span class='b'>b - some really long text and stuff</span></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcubed111/U56cq/

Comment: Is something like this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/U56cq/15/

Comment: Yes, just I need .b to shrink, not just be covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/U56cq/16/

Replace `float:left` with `display:block` and you'd get what you want. The point is: block in normal flow with `overflow:hidden` next to block with `float` would shrink exactly to fit in a space near the floated block.